# symfony - saving blob data image sizes

Tags: symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a form, PhotoForm, which has an emebedded BlobDataForm.

I can save the blbo data fine, my problem comes, with the blob_data table.

I have 2 fields, image_width and image_height.

I'd like to save these details as well, when the blob is saved.

I have overridden doSave();

```
  protected function doSave($con = null)
  {
    if (null === $con)
    {
      $con = $this->getConnection();
    }

    $this->updateObject();
    $blobData = new BlobData();
    $this->saveEmbeddedForms($con);
    $this->getObject()->setBlobData($this->getEmbeddedForm('blob_data')->getObject());
    $this->getObject()->save($con);
  }
```

Would I need to override saveEmbeddedForms() as well?

Thanks

EDIT:

Ok, so it seems i need to override:

> processValues()

I'm just having trouble getting the images width and height attributes.

Does anyone know how I'd do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so after all that, I had to override saveEmbeddedForms:

```
  public function saveEmbeddedForms($con = null, $forms = null)
  {
    if (null === $con)
    {
      $con = $this->getConnection();
    }

    if (null === $forms)
    {
       $photos = $this->getValue('blob_data');
       $forms = $this->embeddedForms;
       foreach ($this->embeddedForms['blob_data'] as $name => $form)
       {
            if (!isset($photos[$name]))
            {
              unset($forms['blob_data'][$name]);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($forms as $form)
    {
      if ($form instanceof sfFormObject)
      {
        $form->saveEmbeddedForms($con);
        $blobData = $form->getObject()->getBlobData();
         $imageStream = stream_get_contents($blobData);
         $image = imagecreatefromstring($imageStream);
         $form->getObject()->setImageWidth(imagesx($image));
         $form->getObject()->setImageHeight(imagesy($image));
         $form->getObject()->setFileExtension('jpg');
         //return parent::preSave($con);
        $form->getObject()->save($con);
      }
      else
      {
        $this->saveEmbeddedForms($con, $form->getEmbeddedForms());
      }
    }
}
```

This seemed to work for me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can get this 2 informations from your blob_data field, you can override the preSave method of your BlobData class which is called just before saving object :

```
public function preSave($event)
{ 
     //get the information from the blob_data
     $this->image_width = ... ;
     $this->image_height = ... ;

}
```

Comment: can you provide me with some further help? I'm not sure how I'd get the values of the width and height. Thanks